# ngrx effects gives Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiSearchEffects {

  @Effect()
  search$: Observable<any>
    = this.actions$
    .ofType(query.ActionTypes.QUERYSERVER)
    .debounceTime(300)
    .map((action: query.QueryServerAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(payload => {
      console.log(payload);
      const nextSearch$ = this.actions$.ofType(query.ActionTypes.QUERYSERVER).skip(1);

      this.searchService.getsearchresults(payload)
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
        .map((response) =>
          ({type: '[Search] Change', payload: response}
          ))
    });
```

above code gives me Argument of type '(payload: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'. 
where could be the mistake be. I have followed the ngrx effects official intro at https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/intro.md .

Comment: your switchMap should return a value... its returning void as you have it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your switchMap should **return** a value; its returning void as you have it.

Try this

```
  return this.searchService.getsearchresults(payload)
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
```

Comment: the answer is mainly the original code, with a return added. You could have commented the tweak instead of making an answer in my opinion

Comment: Strongly agree, in fact there is a solution mentioned already in the comments . But most of the time we believe it's not answered yet and read the whole question . Stackoverflow should give option to mark answered from the comments. If this is against the best practices I can delete it :)